# Optimizing accuracy of different basketball shots

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, error-analysis, biology

I have a high school math project and chose to work on basketball trajectory because I thought I would enjoy it the most. But honestly, I have a hard time calculating a 3D trajectory. So I thought maybe anyone could give me a starting point or an article I could read that would help me so that I can begin my calculations.
What I am basing my observation on:

- the shot is either going to be a floater or 30+ foot shots
- I am taking into consideration both a perfect swish and backboard shots hence the need for 3D impulse after the collision
- I will be taking one player as a subject with the most information on their shot online to ease the workload.

I hope I made my request clear enough because I am on my last legs here and I have no other research question in mind. Any additional tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possibly useful: [Projectile motion in real-life situation: Kinematics of basketball shooting; Changjan & Mueanploy, Journal of Physics: Conference Series 622 (2015): DOI 10.1088/1742-6596/622/1/012008](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/622/1/012008)

Comment: Possibly useful: "Optimizing a Basketball Shot" (Rhett Allain, Wired, Oct 19, 2011) https://www.wired.com/2011/10/optimizing-a-basketball-shot/

Answer (score 1):

Note that I have never played (or even watched a game of) basket-ball, so have no idea what floaters or swishes are (rugby and cricket are more popular in my part of the world). But I am a physicist, so here goes...

Simplification of the problem is probably the key to getting some results.

Start with a 2D model: For your two types of shot consider the range of initial velocity and initial trajectory of the ball that will result in a basket. That should help contrast the precision required for different types of shot.

Add a simplification of the 'back-board: As an approximation, the ball's vertical velicity after hitting teh backboard is unchanged, while it's horizontal velocity is reversed. That can be (very roughly) modelled by removing the backboard and adding a mirrored basket behind the plane of the backboard. Repeat your precision calculations with this model.

Approximate a 3rd dimension: With the above model, you now have a second horizontal velocity component that will be unchanged after hitting the backboard. Try adding the effects of that into your model...

Overall, I don't know exactly what the requirements of your course are but I would guess that a project shgowing insights from simplified models may actually get you more kudos than you would get from developing a full 3D simulation. In addition, once a simulation gets sophisticated enough - say you could add all the complexity of ball-hoop bounces, ball spin, air resistance, relative motion of the athelete to the hoop, - it actually looses its power to *explain* what is happening or *why* it happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a 2D problem for all but the backboard case. You shoot directly at the hoop, so the only directions are vertical and radial towards the hoop.  These can be the y and x directions.

Then for the backboard case, start with the 2D problem where the ball comes in exactly perpendicular to the board, and get that answer.

Finally, try to add the 3rd dimension where it comes in at an angle to the board.

It's not clear exactly what you are after – writing the correct equations, making plots of the trajectories, etc – but the #1 rule in physics is to take a complex problem and start with a simple version of the problem, and work your way up adding complexity as needed.